# Is this a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem where n = 3?

Tags: number-theory

So I have spent some time thinking about Fermat's Last Theorem and about how to come up with a proof for certain cases of n. To begin with I took n = 3.

$$A^3 + B^3 = C^3 (A,B,C \in \mathbb {Z})( A,B,C ≠ 0)$$
We can assume that $A<B<C$.
Because of this we can rewrite this as:
$$A^3 + xA^3 = C^3$$
We now have three possibilities:
$x$ is an integer, $x$ is an irrational, or $x$ is a fraction.

If $x$ is an integer then $x$+1 and $x$ must be cubes. The only numbers which satisfy this are $x$ = 0. However, this means $B^3 = 0$.

$x$ cannot be irrational because then $C^3$ is irrational.
Therefore $x$ is a fraction.

We can represent this now as:
$$A^3 + \frac{p}{q}B^3 = C^3 (p,q \in \mathbb {Z})(GCD(p,q) = 1)$$
This means $\frac{p}{q}$ is actually a cube over a cube. Therefore $p$ and $q$ are cube numbers.

However, $1 + \frac{p}{q}$ is also a cube. Therefore $\frac{p+q}{q}$ is a cube over a cube. Hence: $$\sqrt[3]{p} ,\sqrt[3]{q}, \sqrt[3]{p+q} \in \mathbb {Z}$$

We can now create another variable $v$ for $p+q$.
Therefore, $$p+q = v$$ (Where $\sqrt[3]{v} \in \mathbb {Z}$)

Now we must deal with $\frac{p}{q}+1$. Since this is a cube we can write this as:
$$\frac{p}{q} + 1 = \lambda^3$$
Since $p$ and $q$ are co-prime and in simplest form, $\lambda$ and $\lambda^3$ are also fractions in simplest form. Rearranging, we get:
$$p = q(\lambda^3 - 1)$$

Substituting this into $p+q=v$, we get:
$$q+q(\lambda^3 - 1) = v$$
$$q\lambda^3 = v$$

Since $\lambda^3$ is a fraction, we can express it as $\frac{D^3}{E^3}$.
Hence:
$$qD^3 = vE^3$$

However, because $v$ is a cube, $vE^3$ is also a cube. Therefore $\lambda^3$ doesn't have to be a fraction. This is a contradiction, and so there can be no integer solutions for $p$ and $q$. Subsequently, there can be no integer solutions for A,B,C in:
$$A^3 + B^3 = C^3$$.

If anyone could point out the problem in this and what you think of it it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you justify the sentence “This means $\frac{p}{q}$ is actually a cube over a cube”?

Comment: The very definition of $x$ implies that $x=\frac{B^3}{A^3}$

Comment: "Therefore $\lambda^3$ doesn't have to be a fraction" ? Formulated this way, it could be a fraction, so no contradiction arises. If you mean "$\lambda^3$ cannot be a fraction", then justify why this is the case !

Comment: Why is "$1+\frac pq$ also a cube"?

Comment: After the conclusion that $x$ is a fraction, shouldn't the next formula be $A^3+\frac p q A^3 = C^3$ ?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier that's because $1+p/q=a+A^3/B^3=C^3/B^3$.

Comment: @random You are correct; I'm sure that was a typo from the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$qD^3=v E^3.\tag{1}$$
But if you've followed carefully, you'd have noticed that
$D=C$, $E=B$, $p=A^3$, $q=B^3$ and $v=C^3$. The conclusion given is
then that "$\lambda^3$ doesn't have to be a fraction". I presume
this is intended to mean that $D^3/E^3\notin\Bbb Z$. But (1) says
that $B^3C^3=C^3B^3$. From this tautology, why can we deduce anything
non-trivial at all, let alone $D^3/E^3\notin\Bbb Z$?